# ImageIO.read() works on FileInputStream, not HttpInputStream

Tags: java

I need to get a BufferedImage from an InputStream.

Currently, I can do this by running:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

When **inputStream** is an instance of *FileInputStream*.

However, when **inputStream** is an instance of *HttpInputStream*, the BufferedImage is null.

How can I create a BufferedImage from an *HttpInputStream*?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Are you getting any bytes back from `HttpInputStream`?

Comment: The only thing I see in the HttpInputStream is the URL of the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to read an image from `URL`, you can use `IOUtils` to read the file in `byte` array and then pass `ByteArrayInputStream` to `ImageIO`, e.g.:

```
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(new URL("<url>").openStream());
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
```

`openStream` returns an inputstream and hence, you should be able to create `bufferedImage` object.